# Executing function based on pointer location

Tags: c#, arcgis

I am working with ArcGIS SDK for dot net. I am programming using vc#. I want to execute a piece of code as soon as the mouse pointer enters a particular longitude/latitude on map or if mouse is clicked on that location. there are many event handlers but I don't know how to retrieve the location the mouse pointer is at. e.g I want to display some picture as soon as mouse pointer is at longitude 25 and lat 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `MouseMove` listener to your `MapView`.
2. Your listener method will have a parameter of type `MouseEventArgs`. Call `GetPosition(null)` on that parameter to get the screen point.
3. Use `MapView.ScreenToLocation(Point)` to get the MapPoint in map coordinates.
4. If your map isn't in longitude/latitude, use `GeometryEngine.Project(Geometry, SpatialReference.Create(4326))` to convert to longitude/latitude.
5. Check the longitude and latitude to see if they're in the range you want.

I tried posting my source code here but Stack Overflow gave me an error, so here it is as a screenshot:

[image]